# Get google search results quantity

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I want to do a little programm, that show's the user how much articles/sites/whatever are found with the google search engine.

I found this link here, https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=de#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list?q=btc&cx=g&filter=0&_h=2&

With my api key, I can create a google search box that open's a window with the search results. But thats not exactly what I want to have.

I want that the user writes some search keys on my website like: `summer`, `gaming`, `unicorn` and then I get something like this back:

```
summer => 225000000, // search results
gaming => 18200000, // search results
unicorn => 8651000000, // search results
```

I don't know if this custom search api is exactly that what I'm looking for. I don't really want to code a crawler that gives me some HTML back and cuts the number of results out.

Does someone know, how I can solve this problem? I don't really have a clue where to start.

---

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "ipRefererBlocked", "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.", "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=258028334160" } ], "code": 403, "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions." } }
```

Does someone know how I can fix that? How do I specify a referer?

Comment: Hey, I've noticed you have a few questions without accepting an answer. Just a friendly reminder that you should possibly return to those questions and accept an answer or engage in conversation with those that supplied their time to assist you.

Comment: you are right, I will accept the best answers of my questions in a minute :)

Comment: The extended help can only be accessed by you. Edited my answer to reflect your error edit. You will also need a Custom Search Engine ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST to query the google search engine. Basically, you call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE&q=INSERT_YOUR_KEYWORD_HERE
```

You will receive a JSON file. This has a field named `totalResults`. This is the number of search results that you are looking for.

Relevant links:

- [Using REST to Invoke the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest)
- [Description of the result JSON](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response)

---

Here the answer to your error:

You can chose which restrictions should apply to your api key. You set it to `HTTP Referrer` which means that you have to set the correct HTTP Header.
A better setting would be `IP-Address`. Add all IP addresses of your server and you are good to go.

Comment: I will have a look at this :) I will reply in a minute

Comment: I have updated my question, I tried that out but got the error in my question.

Comment: I registered my website on that api and gave the query the correct key